# Unslider plugin - How to set 3 second delay for first slide

Tags: delay, unslider

```js
$('.banner').unslider({
 speed: 500,               //  The speed to animate each slide (in milliseconds)
 delay: 3000,              //  The delay between slide animations (in milliseconds)
 complete: function() {},  //  A function that gets called after every slide animation
 keys: true,               //  Enable keyboard (left, right) arrow shortcuts
 dots: true,               //  Display dot navigation
 fluid: false              //  Support responsive design. May break non-responsive designs
});
```

```css
.banner { position: relative; overflow: auto; }
    .banner li { list-style: none; }
        .banner ul li { float: left; }
```

```html
<div class="banner">
    <ul>
        <li>This is a slide.</li>
        <li>This is another slide.</li>
        <li>This is a final slide.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://unslider.com/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//unslider.com/unslider.min.js"></script>
```

How can set delay 3 sec first slide(item) only other slide(item) will move 9 sec unslider plugin.

Already plugin has same delay whole slide.

The plugin link http://unslider.com/

Comment: can you mention the plugin your using @anithaappu

Answer (score 0):

As per Unslider documentation it does not have option to **set delay time for each slide** as of now. Try by modifying the library file by yourself.

Include `<link href="http://unslider.com/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>` in your code.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.banner').unslider();
});
```

```css
.banner { position: relative; overflow: auto; }
.banner li { list-style: none; }
.banner ul li { float: left; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://unslider.com/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://unslider.com/unslider.js"></script>


<div class="banner">
  <ul>
    <li>This is a slide.</li>
    <li>This is another slide.</li>
    <li>This is a final slide.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```